# Tensorflow Keras different number of categories in training and validation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm building an image classifier using Keras' built-in Resnet (added to a sequential) and data generators. The images are stored in individual folders, with the folders acting as the classes.

The problem is that there are 464 classes in the training dataset, compared to 683 in the validation dataset. Thus, when I run:

```
model.fit_generator(
    train_datagen, 
    steps_per_epoch = STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
    epochs = EPOCHS,
    verbose = 1,
    callbacks = [cp_callback, cp_tensorboard],
    validation_data = val_datagen,
    validation_freq = 2
)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (464,) but got array with shape (683,)
```

This makes sense; the model trained on the training set can't evaluate classes it doesn't have nodes for. Still, is it possible to modify my model or dataset division to fix this issue?

Alternatively, is there a way to use validation_split with data generators, allowing me to validate without touching a separate dataset?

Comment: You should have data for all the classes in your training dataset, otherwise it doesn't make sense and you won't be able to predict those classes that are not in your training data.

Comment: Use numpy to filter you validation data, and use just the samples that have the same label as train data. Your model is just able to predict samples of classes that it saw in train.

Comment: @AugustoMaillo How do I filter the output from a generator though? do I need to create my own custom generator instead of using the built in ImageDataGenerator class to read the validation data?

Comment: You can create your own custom generator or filter data before define ImageDataGenerator. Use numpy to filter your data. Check np.where, np.any, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain a DataFrame for the validation set which consists only of trained classes. Later you can use Keras **ImageDataGenerator**'s **flow_from_dataframe** function to solve your issue.
You can follow the below code.

```
images = []
classes = []
#To filter classes from validation set 
for i in train_classes:
  image_list = os.listdir("Validation/" + i + "/") 
  cl = [i] * len (image_list)
  images.extend(image_list)
  classes.extend(cl)

val_df = pd.DataFrame({"Images":images, "Classes":classes})

val_datgen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=val_df,
        directory='Validation',
        x_col="Images",
        y_col="Classes",
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')
```

Where train_classes is the list of classes in your training data.